# Given a timestamp, how to show timeago by days/weeks/months

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to show a timeago like output based on a iso timestamp from the db like: 2008-07-17T09:24:17Z

Output should be like:

- Used today
- Used on Tuesday
- Used last Tuesday
- Used more than a month ago

Something simple and more static that what you get with the jQuery timeago plugin: http://timeago.yarp.com/

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the timeago plugin you linked? It is too fine grained?

Comment: What do you really want?

Comment: There are many questions about this in a million places on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the timestamp into a date object and compare it to a local (or some other) date object. Then classify the response based on the difference:

```
// Expects ISO8601 long format, no decimals of seconds
function localDateFromUTC(s) {

  var x = s.split(/[-\s:tz]/i);
  var d = Date.UTC(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], 0);
  return new Date(d);
}

function aboutTime(s) {

  var r = Math.round;
  var now = new Date();
  var then = localDateFromUTC(s);
  var diff = r((now - then)/1000); // Convert to seconds

  if (diff < 10) return 'a few seconds ago';
  if (diff < 50) return 'less than a minute ago';
  if (diff < 70) return 'about a minute ago';
  if (diff < 35000) return 'about ' + r(diff/60) + ' minutes ago';
  if (diff < 8.64e4) return 'about ' + r(diff/3600) + ' hours ago';
  if (diff < 6.048e5) return 'about ' + r(diff/8.64e4) + ' days ago';
  // and so on
  return 'about ' + r(diff/6.048e5) + ' weeks ago';

}

alert(aboutTime('2008-07-17T09:24:17Z')); // about 200 weeks ago
```

You can get more clever regarding how the number is converted to an "about" string (e.g. an object with properties related to the "about" times, then convert the number to a property name).